# Alinhar Texto na vertical com Bootstrap sem altura fixa

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando alinhar o texto na vertical no meu cabeçalho mas parece impossível.

Eu quero que meu conteúdo do cabeçalho sempre esteja no centro verticalmente, eu fiz horizontal mas vertical não consigo.

Obrigado.

Segue o código de exemplo e as imagens:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" style="background-color:gray;">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red; text-align:center;">
                <img src="bootstrap-logo.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; text-align:center;" >
                Quadrado 2
                <br />
                Quadrado 2
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red; text-align:center;">
                Quadrado 3
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; text-align:center;">
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="height:6px; background-color:black;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="background-color:gray;">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red; text-align:center;">
                <img src="bootstrap-logo.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; text-align:center;">
                Quadrado 2
                <br />
                Quadrado 2
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red; text-align:center;">
                Quadrado 3
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; text-align:center;">
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
                Quadrado 4
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Segue as imagens de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o padding-top com o calc.

```
 <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue; padding-top: calc(x + y);">
     Quadrado 2
     <br />
     Quadrado 2
     <br />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red; padding-top: calc(x + y);">
      Quadrado 3
      <br />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aplica estas propriedades de CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alinhamento na vertical:**

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Alinhamento na vertical e horizontal:**

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Podes ver mais informações neste [website](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) é muito bom nessa matéria.